# DELETE unchecked report in SQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkbox

I have reports under a company where if they are unchecked, they should be deleted. To do that, I wish to write it in SQL but I am unsure of how to write whether a report id is checked or unchecked in SQL.

This is my for loop(delete query is inside),

```
 For Each oDataGridItem In valgrid2.Items
        chk = oDataGridItem.FindControl("CheckBox1")
        rn = oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblrptName")
        rid = oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID")
        If chk.Checked = True Then
            rpti = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblReportID"), Label).Text

            valsql2 = "INSERT INTO CompanyReportListTable(CompanyID, ReportID) Values (valCompanyId, rpti) where ReportID <> rpti and companyid <> valCompanyId"
            valsql2 = valsq2 & ";DELETE FROM CompanyReportListTable WHERE ReportID <> chk" 

            count += 1
            rptn = CType(oDataGridItem.FindControl("lblrptName"), Label).Text
            oExArgs.Add(rptn)
            Response.Write(rpti + " - " + rptn + "<br/>")
        End If
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            valgrid2.DataBind()
            Validate()
        End If
    Next
    Response.End()
```

How would I delete an unchecked report in SQL or delete all noncheckpoints?

Comment: Is this in a datagrid? As posted there just isn't any context here to offer much help.

Comment: Yes, the data and checkboxes are indeed in a datagrid.

Comment: You will need to loop through your grid and find all the ReportIDs that are not checked. Then you will need to delete them. I would suggest using a table valued parameter which would contain all the ReportIDs to delete.

Comment: I edited my question to include the for loop in which the query takes place. So Sean, would this mean adding a If chk.Checked = False, or placing that in the delete query?

Comment: With your latest edit you some issues. Your insert statement is not valid. You can't use a list of values and a where clause. I would suggest you do this as a set based approach to the database. Otherwise you will have to execute an insert and a delete for every single row. That is far less than efficient.

Comment: Sean, those values are needed as well as the where clause to specify what and where we want to insert. The query inserts into the two columns from the table. The values are passed from those columns through variables where column ReportID doesn't equal the type rpti and column CompanyID doesn't equal type valcompanyID

Comment: But the syntax is not valid. You need to provide a LOT more information here for anybody to be able to help much. Here is a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: OK, will read into. Thanks!